# Windows can't read certain files I copy to my thecus N4100 NAS

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, nas

I have a strange issue here.
I copy some files to a Thecus N4100 NAS from Windows.
I can read the files on Windows before I copy them, but then I cannot read them
from the NAS anymore. That is to say I can copy them back to Windows, but the files seem to be invalid.

If I read the same files using a MacOS or Linux machine I don't experience any problems.

I have copied files over 10GB and can read those, the files I can't read are like 2GB,
but some files do not cause any problems at all.

The only thing I can notice is that there does not seem to be a Last Access/Modified dates on the files that don't work. Windows shows nothing, Mac OS shows 1975 and todays date.

I have no idea what might be causing this and how to debug it.

Comment: What windows OS? Fully patched?

Comment: Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit and Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit.

Comment: have you tried the thecus forums?